# Help me to vizualise this falling ball on spinning Earth

Tags: geometry, rotations, visualization

[image]

The earth rotates. The ball falls in an latitude, not equator, let say in Germany. I am trying to understand how to express the ball in terms of the angular velocity on the planet. The constant rotation $w$ keeps the ball on the same latitude but the longitude changes hence needing some correction to the $\hat i$ -term and $\hat k$ -term.  The right solution is $w [\sin(\lambda),0,\cos(\lambda)]$ but I cannot see it. $\hat i$ is projected to the z -axis. $\hat k$ is projected to the x -axis, though but I cannot differentiate them yet.

> How to express the falling ball in terms of the constant angular velocity $\bar w$?

Our discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6303283#6303283).